# How to count words and punctuation in a string C program?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program in C which counts the number of words and punctuation marks in a string without using built in functions such as arrays. Is it possible to do so without arrays? Also, my current program is below and gives me an error to initialize *word but I'm trying to have it that the user inputs a string and the program counts it so I do not want to initialize. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    int main(){
        char *word;
        int countword = 0, i;
        int countpunct = 0, i;
        printf("\nEnter the String: ");
        gets(word);
        for (i = 0; word[i] == ' '; i++){
            countword++;
        }
        for (i = 0; word[i] == '.' || '?' || '!' || '(' || ')' || '*' || '&'){
            countpunct++;
        }
        printf("\nThe number of words is %d.", countword);
        printf("\nThe number of punctuation marsks is %d.", countpunct);
        getch();

    }
```

Comment: That long OR `||` sequence is not the right syntax in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to read each characters separately and deal with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if 0
#include<conio.h>
#endif

int main(){
    int word;
    int countword = 0;
    int countpunct = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the String: ");
    while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n'){
        if (word == ' ') countword++;
        if (word == '.' || word == '?' ||  word == '!' ||  word == '(' ||  word == ')' ||  word == '*' ||  word == '&'){
            countpunct++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe number of words is %d.", countword);
    printf("\nThe number of punctuation marsks is %d.", countpunct);
#if 0
    getch();
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more lines of code, but a `switch` statement isn't a bad way to go. The general idea of the code below should work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //for strlen()

int main(){
    char input[255];
    int wcount, pcount, i;
    wcount = pcount = 0;

    printf("\nEnter the String: ");
    fgets(input, 255, stdin);  //use this instead

    for (i=0; i < strlen(input); i++){
        switch (input[i]){
            case ' ':
                if (i > 0) wcount++;
                break;
            case '.':
            case '?':
            case '!':
            case '(':
            case ')':
            case '*':
            case '&':
                pcount++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you group all the cases starting from the second one: `case '.': case '?': case '!': case '(': case ')': case '*': case '&': pcount++; break;`?

Comment: Good point - I was writing quickly and not thinking :) I haven't used switch statements in a long time